# Adaptar (stackpanel) al tamaño maximo? (UserControl)

Tags: c#, wpf, usercontrol

Buenas tardes
¿Como puedo hacer para que al maximizar la ventana padre de mi aplicación la ventana hija, que esta diseñada en un userControl se adapte y ocupe todo el stackPanel al que esta conteniendolo?

Para muestra un Boton (nunca mejor dicho);

UserControl (ventana hija)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la ventana principal, el `stackPanel` marcado es el que ocupara el `UserControl`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado es el siguiente;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me gustaría es que el `ControlTab` ocupase siempre el alto máximo de la ventana padre

MainWindow:

```
     <DockPanel>
       <StackPanel Name="stackPanel1" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="120">
          <Button x:Name="Boton" Content="Boton" Click="Boton_Click"></Button>
       </StackPanel>
       <StackPanel Name="stackPanel2" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  Height="80" />
       <StackPanel Name="stackPanel3" />
     </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Probablemente no es un `StackPanel` lo que debes usar, sino un `DockPanel` por ejemplo. De todas maneras, sería bueno que mostraras el xaml de tu mainwindow, o un [mcve]

Comment: El MainWindow tan solo es eso, cuando cargo el UserControl1.xaml en el stackPanel3 ocurre lo que muestro en las capturas

Comment: Prueba a cambiarlo por Dockpanel como te digo a ver

Comment: Gracias, eso era... me estaba obcecando con el codigo del UserControl1.xaml sin mirar el del MainWindow...